# Mongodb query multiple collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have two collection

**user**

```
[{
    "id":1,
    "name":"a1",
    "emailAddress":"1@s.com",
},
{
    "id":2,
    "name":"a2",
    "emailAddress":"2@s.com",
},
{
    "id":3,
    "name":"a3",
    "emailAddress":"3@s.com",
}]
```

**Organaziation**

```
[{
    "emailAddress": "1@s.com",
    "name" : "org1"
},
{
    "emailAddress": "2@s.com",,
    "name" : "org1"
},
{
    "emailAddress" : "3@s.com",
    "name" : "org2"
}]
```

Now I want to fetch all users for organization **org1** like below

```
[{
    "id":1, "name":"a1", "emailAddress":"1@s.com","orgName" : "org1"
},
{
    "id":2, "name":"a2", "emailAddress":"2@s.com","orgName" : "org1"
}]
```

I have checked debRef and lookup but those are returning in nested

How can I acheive this?

Comment: using mongoose or mongodb driver ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply achieve this using [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) and [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) aggregations

If you have mongodb version **3.6** and above

```
db.users.aggregate([
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": Organisation.collection.name,
    "let": { "emaildid": "$emaildid" },
    "pipeline": [
      { "$match": { "$expr": { "$eq": [ "$emaildid", "$$emaildid" ] } } }
    ],
    "as": "organisation"
  }},
  { "$unwind": "$organisation" },
  { "$project": {
    { "id": 1, "name": 1, "emailid": 1, "org": "$organisation.org1" }
  }}
])
```

If you have mongodb version **3.4** and below

```
db.users.aggregate([
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": Organisation.collection.name,
    "localField": "emaildid",
    "foreignField": "emaildid",
    "as": "organisation"
  }},
  { "$unwind": "$organisation" },
  { "$project": {
    { "id": 1, "name": 1, "emailid": 1, "org": "$organisation.org1" }
  }}
])
```

try with [`$replaceRoot`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/) as well

```
db.Organisation.aggregate([
  { "$match": { "name": "org1" }},
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": Organisation.collection.name,
    "let": { "emailAddress": "$emailAddress", "name": "$name" },
    "pipeline": [
      { "$match": { "$expr": { "$eq": [ "$emailAddress", "$$emailAddress" ] } } },
      { "$addFields": { "orgName": "$$name" }}
    ],
    "as": "users"
  }},
  { "$unwind": "$users" },
  { "$replaceRoot": { "newRoot": "$users" } }
])
```

Comment: You need to aggregate with **users** collection and `$lookup` with **organisation** collection... See the updated answer... and make sure you put correct collection name inside `$lookup` i.e. in `Organisation.collection.name`

Comment: I manage to get data using  ----- db.userorganizations.aggregate([ 
 
  { $match: { "organization" : "test", }},
  {$lookup: {
    from: "users", 
    localField: "emailAddress",
    foreignField: "emailAddress",
    as: "userdetails"}
  }

Comment: Check the updated answer and please delete all the comments

Comment: unfortunately its not working, Could you please help me how can I get required fields from both collection in this query  ----- b.userorganizations.aggregate([ { $match: { "organization" : "test", }}, {$lookup: { from: "users", localField: "emailAddress", foreignField: "emailAddress", as: "userdetails"} }---

Comment: Sorry not possible because I have put them into my collections and checked and get same output as you posted in your question... Please post the query in your question which you have tried

Comment: You can use `$project` aggregation to limit your fields

Comment: I am facing issue there in my previous query as well, not able to do that, could you please help

Comment: When I use $project gives me invalid property id error

Comment: your above issue has been resolved because your expected output and query output is same ... If you have new doubt then please ask a new question... thanks!!!